JSON_VALUE() not working in select statement but does work in where clause
I'm using Log Analytics which lets you query logs with BQ SQL syntax.
I don't understand why this works:
SELECT
  timestamp, 
FROM
  `my_logs`
WHERE
  JSON_VALUE(resource.labels.project_id) = "my-project"

And this returns Unrecognized name: project_id
SELECT
  timestamp, 
  JSON_VALUE(resource.labels.project_id) as project_id,
FROM
  `my_logs`
WHERE
  project_id = "my-project"

How do I extract a json field and alias in a SELECT statement with BQ SQL?
